# How to force gSOAP to generate vector of objects (not pointers!) for any XSD style?

Tags: c++, xml, data-binding, xsd, gsoap

I've been playing with *gSOAP XML Data Binding* and noticed that class generation varies depending on the XML schema style. Let me show you an example:

**library.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>
    <book isbn="0132350882"/>
    <book isbn="020161622X"/>
    <book isbn="0201633612"/>
</library>
```

**Case 1: XML schema written in the Russian doll style**

**library.xsd** (Russian doll style - generated by Visual Studio 2010 from XML above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="library">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="book">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="isbn" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I am using the following sequence in order to get proxy files (header and source):

`c:\test\gSOAP_Test1>wsdl2h.exe -t "c:\tools\gsoap_2.8.6\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\typemap.dat" Library.xsd`

`c:\test\gSOAP_Test1>soapcpp2.exe -I "c:\tools\gsoap_2.8.6\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\import" Library.h`

For Russian doll styled XSD gSOAP generates classes with following design:

**soapStub.h**:

```
class SOAP_CMAC _ns1__library_book
{
public:
    std::string isbn;   /* required attribute */
    ...
};

class SOAP_CMAC _ns1__library
{
public:
    std::vector<_ns1__library_book >book;   /* required element of type ns1:library-book */
    ...
};
```

Note that `_ns1__library`'s member `book` is implemented as **vector of `_ns1__library_book`  objects**. But this is not the case when we provide schema written in other styles where it is implemented as **vector of pointers**.

**Case 2: XML schema written in the Venetian blind style**

**library.xsd** (Venetian blind):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="book_t">
    <xs:attribute name="isbn" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="library_t">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="book" type="book_t" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="library" type="library_t"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**soapStub.h**:

```
class SOAP_CMAC ns1__book_USCOREt
{
public:
    std::string isbn;   /* required attribute */
        ...
};
#endif

class SOAP_CMAC ns1__library_USCOREt
{
public:
    std::vector<ns1__book_USCOREt * >book;  /* required element of type ns1:book_t */
    ...
};
```

**Case 3: XML schema written in the Sliced salami style**

**library.xsd** (Sliced salami):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="book">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="isbn" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="library">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="book" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**soapStub.h**:

```
class SOAP_CMAC _ns1__book
{
public:
    std::string isbn;   /* required attribute */
    ...
};
#endif

class SOAP_CMAC _ns1__library
{
public:
    std::vector<_ns1__book * >ns1__book;    /* required element of type ns1:book */
    ...
}
```

For the XML provided, I prefer `_ns1__library`'s book collections member to be vector of objects - not a vector of pointers. I want to create instance of `_ns1__book` on the stack and simply pass it (by reference) to vector's `push_back()`. This is possible only for Russian doll-styled schemas.

How to force gSOAP to generate collection of elements member as vector of objects for any schema style? Shall some special arguments be provided to *wsdl2h.exe* and/or *soapcpp2.exe*? Shall XML schema document contain any additional elements?